# Fixed primes in discrete logarithm

Tags: discrete-logarithm

The discrete logarithm problem is to find $z$ when the inputs are $g,h,p$ where $g^z\bmod p$.

Supposing if you fix $p$ then does the problem become any easier to attacks and is there a $(\log p)^c$ complexity algorithm?

Comment: Do you mean that if one has already spend time to solve a given discrete logarithm, say finding $z_1$ from $h_1 = g^{z_1} \bmod p$, is it easier to solve an other discrete logarithm, say finding $z_2$ from $h_2 = g^{z_2} \bmod p$.  For example, by re-using some precomputations made in the resolution of the first discrete logarithm?

Comment: Once you fix $p$, there is a constant-time algorithm: Simply try all possibilities. Asymptotics do not make sense when the instance size is bounded; you need a different notion of complexity in that case.

Comment: I'll write a more complete answer later, but in short: yes, there as algorithms which, given p, can precompute the discrete logarithm so that any discrete log is easy to compute next  (but the setting you describe is not formal, in particular talking about asymptotic complexity is not relevant here). You can have for example a few weeks of precomputation, and then each discrete log will be computed in a few minutes.

Comment: @GeoffroyCouteau Please do write an answer if you have time. If a question deserves an answer it probably also deserves an upvote.

Comment: @GeoffroyCouteau this is great what is the reference? what should i search in literature for this?

Comment: I'll have to search a bit before answering, I remember a talk of Antoine Joux where he mentionned it

Answer (score 1):

The best algorithm for computing discrete logarithms are based on families and variations of methods known as "number field sieve" and "function field sieve". They all share a common structure. In particular, they are divided in several phases, only the last of which depends on the value whose discrete logarithm must be computed: all the previous steps require only the order of the field.

I did some research. I do not know about the computational complexity of each step, this would involve some more research but can probably be found in some of the articles and surveys of Antoine Joux. However, I'll focus on the case which seems to be your target: discrete logarithm in prime order field. For that case, the actual record is a discrete log in a field of order $p$, with $bitsize(p) = 530$. You'll find [Here](https://listserv.nodak.edu/cgi-bin/wa.exe?A2=ind1406&L=NMBRTHRY&F=&S=&P=3161) the report on this record. The computation is divided in five phases: polynomial selection, sieving, filtering, linear algebra, and actual computation of the discrete logarithm. Among them, the sieving is by far the dominant cost: the report indicates it took approximately 50 core-years on a 2-GHz Intel E5-2650. This phase depends only on the order $p$ of the field. The report mention that once the four first phases have been performed, "Computing one individual logarithm required a few hours". Therefore, Compared to the overall time, computing discrete logarithms is extremely fast once the precomputation has been made (with the order of the field only).

Although I do not know the theoretical complexity of this last step, I'm pretty sure that this is still not polynomial time (id est, $O(\log^c p)$ for some $c$), even if it is only a negligible cost in the total computation.

Comment: Thank you. You said you can avoid the guess of $O(log^cp)$ but what is your best guess?

Comment: Sadly, I do not have much intuition regarding this topic - I'm by no mean a specialist, I just happened to hear about those running times during some talk, and did some research (mostly via Wikipedia) to find articles with concrete benchmarks. I've tried to look at some more articles but they do not seem to precisely provide a complexity for each step - it could however probably be determined with a more in-depth reading, but I'd rather hope for someone more knowledgeable to answer :)
But if I absolutely had to give a guess, I might bet on L(1/3) for this step, as for the other steps.

Comment: @Turbo: I just found this very interesting [post](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=2293) on Aaronson's blog. It does target the Diffie-Hellman key exchange protocol but current known attacks on the latter involve computing a discrete logarithm anyway. It gives some interesting estimations on the time it takes to precompute discrete log over finite fields, and then to perform individual discrete logs. You should look at it!

Comment: I have looked at it and it does not explicitly state $(\log ^cp)$ estimates post pre-computation steps.

Comment: Sure, and I'm now pretty convince that this step is not $O(\log^c p)$, but $L(1/3)$ as the others. The point of those articles is just that for practical parameters corresponding to everyday crypto, this last step can nevertheless be executed within a very small amount of time.

Comment: small amount of time is not compatible with $L(1/3)$ right?

Comment: My recollection is that only very small characteristics ( not relevant for discrete logs in a secure crypto system) yield anything like a somewhat feasible algorithm.

Comment: I re-read Scott Aaronson's post. In fact, he explicitely states that even after precomputation, computing individual discrete log is still subexponential - but a "milder" subexponential, which, in practices, means that it can lead to reasonable running times if
1 - you had a huge precomputation time given the modulus $p$ and
2 - $p$ was taken "not that big" (e.g. with a size which was a recommanded parameter in standards that are now considered a bit old)

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not get easier and this is easy to see. Since p is public, everybody can make arbitrary many instances of a DL system with that p.  You cannot diminish complexity by  that means. If you could, such a scheme would bem consideed as broken or at least assigned a lower complexity in the first place.

Comment: Hardcoding the modulus $p$ in the definition of the protocol, hence constantly reusing the same $p$ throughout many instances of the protocol, is already considered "broken" in the theory community - or at least "a very bad habit". We have algorithms which are extremely fast at computing individual discrete logs given lot of precomputation time with $p$.

Comment: Its neither broken nor bad habit. For instance, Nist Fips 186-4 explicitly allows sharing the donain parameters.

Comment: That's why I said "in the theory community"

Comment: could you please provide some precise argument or a papers from the 'theory community"?

Comment: I gave a link to a post by d

Comment: Woops, posted my answer by mistake and it seems I cannot edit it from the phone app... Anyway, I gave a link to a post by Scott aaronson on this topic in a comment above where I answered to turbo. My other sources are two talks, one by Antoine Joux at ens paris and à talk at the crypto 2015 conference  - however I do not know whether the slides are available.

Comment: Scott Aaronson does not say that DH can be broken more easily if p will be reused many times. What he says is that  _if_  DH is broken once _then_  further DH instances can be broken much easier. That is a completöy different statement.

Comment: "But there’s one crucial further fact, which has been understood for at least a decade by theoretical cryptographers, but somehow was slow to filter out to the people who deploy practical cryptosystems.  The further fact is that in NFS, you can arrange things so that almost all the discrete-logging effort depends only on the prime number p, and not at all on the specific numbers g and h for which you’re trying to take the discrete log. ", his statement is clear; to break DDH you compute the discrete log, and most of the effort for that purpose require p only.